# Adobe Omniture For Android

Tags: android, adobe-analytics

i am new to adobe Omniture,i get Started from this link [here](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/android/index.html#Developer_Quick_Start),what should i enter in the below mention two id's in

> TrakingHelper.java

```
private static final String TRACKING_RSID = "rsid";//---->this
private static final String TRACKING_SERVER = "server";//---->this
```

when i registered an app i got only secret code,please post any link with android and omniture integration tutorial,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**TRACKING_RSID (report suite id)**

rsid is the report suite id you want to send the data to. You need to create a report suite in the Adobe Marketing Cloud interface to get the rsid. When you create a report suite, you specify what the rsid for it will be. All of your rsids will have whatever prefix Adobe assigned your account.

To get to that in the Adobe Marketing Cloud interface, you must have an admin account.  When you log in, click on the giant `Adobe Marketing Cloud` breadcrumb at the top left. This will open up a dropdown.  Navigate to `Reports & Analytics > Admin Tools`. Then click on `Report Suites` in the left navigation bar.

All of the report suites you currently have are listed on this page. You will see in the first column the rsid of the report suite, and the description on the right (you also specify this during report suite creation). The value in the first column is what you will use in your code. You can send data to multiple report suites at the same time, by delimiting them with a comma (no spaces inbetween):

`private static final String TRACKING_RSID = "rsid1,rsid2";`

Note that there are extra charges involved in sending to multiple report suites. Review your contract, talk to your Adobe Client Care rep.

If you do not have any report suites created yet, you can create them by clicking on the `Create new > Report Suite` link, located just above the report suite listing on that page. The input field where you specify what you want your rsid to be will show the prefix assigned for your account. Do not include it in what you type in; the system will automatically prepend the prefix, and you will use the full rsid including prefix in your code (the value you see in the "preview" text when you enter it in).

**TRACKING_SERVER**

Your Adobe Client Care representative should have given you this value when you started your subscription. There is a way to get it within the interface, though it's kind of tricky. Adobe has been doing redesign on the interface and so far they are yet to make the TRACKING_SERVER value dynamically generate in the new code manager interface.  However, they do provide a link to their legacy code manager, and it will show up there.

To get to that in the Adobe Marketing Cloud interface, you must have an admin account.  When you log in, click on the giant `Adobe Marketing Cloud` breadcrumb at the top left. This will open up a dropdown.  Navigate to `Reports & Analytics > Admin Tools`. Then click on `Code Manager` in the left navigation bar.

This page shows a listing of code-base and documentation. You can see in that list the Android implementation, and a link to the online [Android Developer Guide](https://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/android/index.html).  So as far as getting the tracking server, down underneath the listing is this:

> To view the legacy code manager or download AppMeasurement libraries
>   for BlackBerry, Windows Phone 7, or Symbian **click here**.

Click on the "click here" link to open up the legacy code manager. The tracking server is the same value regardless of code implementation or rsid or any other value in the form, so just select "Javascript" and pick an rsid etc.. and click the `Generate Code` button.

You should now be on a page that shows two tabs: `Page Code` and `Core Javascript File`, click on `Core Javascript File` and look for these 2 lines:

```
s.visitorNamespace=".."
s.trackingServer=".."
```

The code should show the specific values for your account. The `s.trackingServer` is the value that you should use for `TRACKING_SERVER` variable.  But I also point out `s.visitorNamespace` because that value may also come up in your implementation.

Comment: click here on your post not working you tag it as code i think

Comment: @appubala I didn't make it a link because it is a dynamically generated link, specific to your session in the Adobe interface. That's why I gave you instructions on how to find it in the interface. You will need to navigate to that page and click on the link there

Comment: Any idea about pricing structure of Adobe Mobile Services. I want to purchase this and integrate in my app.